# Are finite-dimensional normed spaces injective?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

A Banach space $X$ is said to be injective if every linear continuous $T:Y\to X$, with $Y\subseteq Z$ Banach spaces, has a linear continuous extension $T^*:Z\to X$ with the same operator-norm.

My question is: is every finite-dimensional normed space $X$ injective?

All examples I know are infinite-dimensional and besides they're not so simple.

Any hint? Thank you.

Comment: The $1$-dimensional version is surely the Hahn-Banach theorem. Are there any subtleties in going from $1$-dimensional $X$ to $n$-dimensional $X$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown got it, thank you